# Unable to get access_token from Twitter api using oauth2.0

Tags: api, twitter, authorization, access-token

I ma trying to get access token from twitter Api to send Direct message but I am keep on getting Something Went wrong message.

I am using correct Client_id and Client_Secret from developer tool.

I am trying on Postman and also using console app but no success

Can someone please help me.

I am excepting to get access token from Twitter API